# Configure PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a `Spring Boot` application where I pass in the property sources like:

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties","file:C:/MyFolder/project.properties"})
```

And everything gets wired perfectly. However, when I attempt to do the same programatically like:

```
@Bean
public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() throws URISyntaxException {
  PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer proprty =  new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
  proprty.setLocations(new Resource[] {
                                        new ClassPathResource("application.properties"),
                                        new FileSystemResource("C:/MyFolder/project.properties")});
  return proprty;
}
```

It doesn't work. It cannot find the properties defined in `C:/MyFolder/project.properties`. Any ideas?

The stacktrace I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.utilisoft.backfill.Application.main(Application.java:108)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
```

Obviously I cannot determine the database settings. They are defined in `project.properties` file which doesn't get wired when I programatically set up the properties.

Comment: try new FileSystemResource("C:\\MyFolder\\project.properties");

Comment: Why? Spring Boot already provides that support out of the box. Only adding a `@PropertySource` for your specific `project.properties` is enough. Why make it more complex?

Comment: @prem kumar it doesn't work

Comment: @ M. Deinum I will get the location of the spring boot .jar file and from there I will get the properties. I don't know where  the location of the jar as well as the properties file will be extracted initially. That's why I need to dynamically load the properties based on the .jar location. project.properties will be in an external folder. I can't just hard code it.

Comment: What you provided works fine for me. Please clarify what you mean by _doesn't work_ and provide a [MCVE].

Comment: I've added the stacktrace. It's obvious that it doesn't work because of the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configuration. When I use the annotation  @PropertySource it all works perfectly fine!!!

Comment: Again why? Seems like an ugly contraption, regardless Spring Boot already loads the `application.properties` for you. Instead of registering your own placeholder (which might and will interfere with the Spring Boot one, which by turn is also a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instead of a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`). You can pass in additional property files to load from the command line, and if you want something more complex add an `ApplicationContextInitializer` and add your file to the collection of `PropertySources` on the `Environment`. Work with the framework not against it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve exactly what you're looking for without either the annotation or defining it programmatically, from the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

> Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is designed to allow sensible overriding of values, properties are considered in the following order:
>
> 1. Command line arguments.
> 2. Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property)
> 3. JNDI attributes from java:comp/env.
> 4. Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
> 5. OS environment variables.
> 6. A RandomValuePropertySource that only has properties in random.*.
> 7. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
> 8. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
>   Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
>
>   Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
> 9. @PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes.
> 10. Default properties (specified using SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties).

In other words, if you have an `application.properties` file in your `src/main/resources` for development (point 10 above), and an external one next to your `jar` file for production (point 9 above), the correct properties will be picked up automatically.

Comment: How do `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` impls fall into this list?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lifecycle problem...you're creating a bean with properties that aren't yet set (as you know).  Initialize your database in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`. See this paragraph on [initialization callbacks](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean). In short it says the `InitializingBean` interface:

> ...allows a bean to perform initialization work after all necessary
>   properties on the bean have been set by the container.

It then goes on to say to use `@PostConstruct` instead of the `InitializingBean` interface so your code isn't unnecessarily coupled to Spring.

Answer (score 0):

If you check DatasourceProperties.java [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.java), you will see that configuration is bound using a ConfigurationProperties annotation. The processing of this annotation is documented in [configuration externalization documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). None of the mentioned resolution steps rely on the implementation you provided.